# Flutter : Future builder not updating form values

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

Using Future builder, able to populate earlier saved values of form fields at the time of page loading.
But when snapshot is null, it has to display empty form

This below code is working fine when form has some initials values

```
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            body: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,      
              child:FutureBuilder(
                future: _getPersonalInfoFormInitialValue(),
               builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.hasData ? buildFormBuilder(context, snapshot.data) : Center(child: Text('Loading .....')),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );

  }
```

This code is working fine when snapshot.data is null, its displaying empty form as expected

```
FutureBuilder(
            future: _getPersonalInfoFormInitialValue(),
           builder: (context, snapshot) => buildFormBuilder(context, snapshot.data) ,
          ),
```

So I have combined both to get the form working for all cases as,

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,      
          child:FutureBuilder(
            future: _getPersonalInfoFormInitialValue(),
           builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.hasData ? buildFormBuilder(context, snapshot.data) : buildFormBuilder(context, null) ,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

buildFormBuilder method :

```
FormBuilder buildFormBuilder(BuildContext context, data) {
        return FormBuilder(
          key: _personalDetailFormKey,
          initialValue: data ?? {},
          autovalidate: true,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
                 .........
                          _submitButton(() {
                            _submitPersonalDetailInfoForm();
                          }, 'Submit'), 
            ],
          ),
        );
  }
```

_getPersonalInfoFormInitialValue

```
_getPersonalInfoFormInitialValue() async {
    return _personalInfo!=null ? _personalInfo.toPersonalInfoMap() : null;
  }
```

So now, in both the cases, its displaying only empty fields of the form. eventhough snapshot.data has the values but its not populating into form fields.
I have tried with Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 10), () {}); still facing issue.

Something is getting wrong somewhere, not able to identify, any help appreciated !! Thanks

Comment: Share the code for the custom widget.

Comment: @ASADHAMEED buildFormBuilder code added

Comment: Still not clear, you may share code for tye future!

Comment: thats all the code... rest is form normally fields and nothing else

Comment: I'm talking about the code for future that is assigned to the future builder.

Comment: code added @ASADHAMEED

Comment: Where is this variable `_personalInfo` getting data from? Or why are you expecting it to notbe null?‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because FutureBuilder is not a child:

```
FutureBuilder(
            future: _getPersonalInfoFormInitialValue(),
           builder: (context, snapshot) => buildFormBuilder(context, snapshot.data) ,
          ),
```

Maybe this works because Futurebuilder is not a child and in the next one it is:

child:FutureBuilder

Comment: in both the cases its child only, the second future builder, mentioned, also worked as well.
first future builder also worked, but wen tried to combine both the code, at that time it doesnt work